# Align images properly

Tags: html, css, image

This is probably easy to you guys but I am having some trouble with the aligning my images so they're even and not one higher than the other. Please see screenshot..

http://puu.sh/3Sgy7.png

Code (I don't use CSS):

```
<img src="images/paypal.png" title="We accept PayPal!"/>
<img src="images/windows.png" title="Windows Server 2008 R2" />
```

I want them to be on the same line and even.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your current code? We'll need that to help you out. Also, you may want to consider re-phrasing your question, as it seems like you are just asking us to the work for you...

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Are the images cropped to the edges of the content?

Comment: Please formulate your question better...and Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PHPglue +1 for the friendly welcome message, but it looks like OP has been a member since December. :-)

Comment: Updated original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Float both images left and make sure there is enough width to fit them side by side.